# script/plugin : not running on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip, a Rails pluging for file upload. I'm following the Railscast about it for setting it up. In the Railscasts at http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip, R.B. runs the following command to install plugins :

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/path_to_plugin
```

When I tried running  :

```
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/path_to_plugin
```

on my Windows PC, nothing happened at first. So I went to check the content of the file at script/plugin but there were none, so I went ahead and created one as it is done in the source code used in the cast at

```
https://github.com/railscasts/134-paperclip/blob/master/store/script/plugin
```

So now my 
Now I get the following error message :

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load --
script/../config/boot (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from script/plugin:2:in `<main>'
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: what version of rails are you using? if you are on 3+ you should add `gem 'paperclip'` to the `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`.

Comment: Yes I am. Is installing a gem for Paperclip equivalent to installing a plugin for Paperclip though ? I wanted to get it from Github, as I'm sure it'd be the most up-to-date source.

Comment: Yes, rails 2 uses plugin a lot but now uses `gems` that are equivalent. You can find more info on https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: Put `gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"` in your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` to get it installed.